# Google App Engine and Cloud Storage Versioned Files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-client, google-app-engine-php

I'm working on an App Engine project that requires revisions of uploaded files be stored and retrieved with revisions. Google Cloud Storage has this feature built in, but as far as I could find they only document this feature with the use of gsutil. Is there a way I could do this with the App Engine API or with the Google Client API for PHP?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't know about the PHP client library, but the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) supports a `generation` parameter.

Comment: I might just have to use that. Oh well.